# Escape * asterisk in raw_input python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Newbie here.
I'm would like to use raw_input() to select a file that ends in .raw from the directory. How do I pass the * as a literal to python? Thank you.

```
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = '*.raw'
try:
    fname = open(fname)
except:
    print fname, ('File Not Found')
exit()
```

Comment: You can't do that. The shell does the globbing, so you need a way to simulate that.

Comment: Also, format your code

Comment: it seems  like you're looking for `glob.glob()` but it's not really clear; your code snipped dosen't include `raw_input()`

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen here if the glob pattern matches multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work like that – shell wildcards are a different beast.

You need to use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) or similar to expand a wildcard pattern.

```
pattern = raw_input('Enter filename or pattern')
files = glob.glob(pattern)
if not files:
     print('No matching files.')
open(files[0]) # ...
```